# Specifying number of clusters and members in CommunityGraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks, cluster-analysis

**The Issue**

I am trying to specify the number of clusters and the number of members in each cluster that the CommunityGraphPlot function forms as part of a larger project.

**The Code**

This code generates a complete graph with a random edge weight between 0 and 1 assigned between each node. It then outputs a community graph plot, choosing communities based on some algorithm.

```
n = 10;
q = n * (n - 1)/2;
g = CompleteGraph[n, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, {q}]];
FindGraphCommunities[g];
CommunityGraphPlot[g, 
 Method -> "Hierarchical",(*EdgeLabels\[Rule]"EdgeWeight",*) 
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: The output plot]

**The Question**

This function is something of a black box, and while reviewing the documentation, I was unable to find any options to specify how many clusters it forms, or how many members are in each cluster. Are there workarounds to this issue?

Also I would appreciate if anyone could point me towards any literature on the methods used to choose clusters, or any other functions that could be used to specify the number of clusters, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> CommunityGraphPlot[g]
> ```

will find community based on

> ```
> FindGraphCommunities[g]
> ```

So that

> ```
> CommunityGraphPlot[g]
> ```

is the same as

> ```
> CommunityGraphPlot[g, FindGraphCommunities[g]]
> ```

You could put labels like the following to show # of members:

```
n = 10;
q = n*(n - 1)/2;
g = CompleteGraph[n, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, {q}]];
com = FindGraphCommunities[g];
member = Length /@ com;
CommunityGraphPlot[g, com, Method -> "Hierarchical", 
 CommunityLabels -> member, ImageSize -> Full, 
 PlotLabel -> "# cluster: " <> ToString[Length[com]]]
```

[image: labeled community graph]

For controlling size of cluster, `FindGraphPartition` can be useful. For example, find the partition of 3 clusters with {5, 3, 2} members.

```
n = 10;
q = n*(n - 1)/2;
g = CompleteGraph[n, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, {q}]];
comm = FindGraphPartition[g, {5, 3, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 6, 7}, {3, 10}}
> ```

and use this set to visualize the result with `CommunityGraphPlot`:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g, comm]
```

[image: community graph]

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. However, I don't think you answered my question.

Comment: Which part you didn't get it?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question, but I am looking for an option in the function that allows me to specify how many clusters the function will form, as well as allow me to specify how many members are in each one of the clusters. I want to be able to specify these things in the argument to `CommunityGraphPlot`.

Comment: There are no such options in `CommunityGraphPlot`, but you can put any set of lists as second argument. You might want to check `FindGraphPartition`.

Comment: Ok, upon closer review of your answer, I do believe you've addressed all parts of my question fully. Thank you very much!